# Can I easily deduce this stronger spectral theorem from this weaker one?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

I've just read a nice proof that:

For $T$ a self-adjoint bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space $E$, there exists a unique $C^*$-algebra isomorphism $C(\sigma (T)) \rightarrow A_T$, from the space of continuous complex-valued functions on the spectrum with the $L^\infty$ norm to the closure (in the norm topology) of the space of operators on $E$ which are polynomials in T.

However I need the slightly different result that this extends to an isomorphism from the space of essentially bounded Borel-measurable functions on the spectrum (again with the $L^\infty$ norm) to the closure, this time in the *strong operator topology*, of the polynomials in T.

Is there an easy way to supplement the former to get the latter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking is how to extend from the $C^*$-closure to the von Neumann closure. Here is a fairly earthy way to do it, using Riesz-Markov representation:

Let $f \mapsto f(T)$ be the continuous functional calculus/your $C^*$-map. For any pair $\xi_1, \xi_2 \in E$,
the map

$$
f \mapsto \langle \xi_1, f(T)\xi_2\rangle
$$

is of the form $\int f d\mu_{\xi_1, \xi_2}$ for some Radon measure $\mu_{\xi_1, \xi_2}$ on $\sigma(T)$ by Riesz-Markov. This allows you to extend the continuous functional calculus to $L^{\infty}(\sigma(T))$: Let $g \in L^{\infty}$,

$$
(\xi_1, \xi_2) \mapsto \int g d\mu_{\xi_1, \xi_2}
$$

is a bounded sesquilinear form on $E \times E$, (bounded by  $\|g\|_{L^{\infty}}$). So for a fixed $\xi_2$, there exists a unique $\eta$ such that 
$$
\langle \xi_1, \eta \rangle \; =\; \int g d\mu_{\xi_1, \xi_2}.
$$

Define $g(T)\xi{_2} = \eta$.

Comment: Thanks +1.  If you feel like it, could you supply the details about how to get $g(T)$ from the functions $<\zeta, g(T)\zeta>$?  In general, when does a function $\lambda: E \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ determine an operator T so that $\lambda (\zeta)=<\zeta, T(\zeta)>$?

Comment: Riesz representation for $E^*$. I'll supply details later if someone doesn't beat me to it.

Comment: I elaborated a bit.

Comment: Thanks but I'm still a little confused.  I agree that $\exists \eta (\forall \xi ( \int g d\mu_\xi = \langle \xi , \eta \rangle))$.  But then I don't know what it means to send $\xi$ to $\eta$ since $\eta$ doesn't seem to depend on $\xi$. Or, more precisely, it looks like a constant map. Sorry if I'm just being thick headed.

Comment: Of course $\eta$ depends on $\xi$---the functional is defined using $\mu_{\xi}$. Essentially $\eta$ is identified with $\mu_{\xi}$, after passing through couple maps. Come on dude, get some coffee.

Comment: I'm pretty well caffeinated and I don't see how the statement $\exists \eta (\forall \xi (\int g d\mu_\xi = \langle \xi , \eta \rangle ))$ gives a definition of $\eta$ in terms of $\xi$.  I think maybe you're thinking about quantifiers in the wrong order (flipping $\forall$ and $\exists$)? If I'm wrong I apologize and thanks for being patient with me.

Comment: So $\mu _\xi$ is a functional on $L^\infty(\sigma (T))$. But it seems like you want $\mu _\xi$ to be a functional on the Hilbert space $E$, and I'm not sure how to consider $\mu _\xi$ as a functional on $E$.

Comment: Ah! The new version looks much more plausible!  Thank you! :)